# Unsupported engine for Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to install Angular on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Therefore i installed nodejs and npm (with nvm):
**node: v14.17.2
npm: 6.14.4**
But i have got this message:

[npm WARN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3E1d.png)

Comment: Hi Lucas, welcome to SO! These messages are warnings, and you can 'ignore' it. Angular recommends use some range version with node, and you are out of the range.  That's why you see these messages.

Comment: you are usig node10 for you commands. switch to newer version via nvm